# DBで注文履歴確認したい

Tags: sqlite, ec-cube

EC-CUBEを初めて使う初心者です。
Cloud9を使いEC-CUBE4をインストールしました。

一度ローカルで買い物をし、注文確定まで行い
DBで確認しようとしたところdtb_orderテーブルがないとエラーが出ました。

Cloud9にデフォルトで入っているmysqlを起動させながらインストールしたのですが
EC-CUBEに適用されていたのは同じくデフォルトではいっているsqlite 3.7.17でした。

`/ec-cube/var/sessions` に `eccube.db` というファイルを見つけ、開いてみたら購入履歴が記載されていました。
今後はDBをCUIで操作して情報変更を行いたいと思っているので、なんとかsqliteからテーブルを引き出し情報確認をしたいのですが、現在どういう状態になっているのか理解ができていません。

Cloud9のsqliteとEC-CUBEがうまく適応できていないのでしょうか？
もしそうなのであれば解決策を教えていただきたいです。
的外れな質問だった場合は申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 0):

質問文に記載されている内容から、次のことが分かります。

- EC-CUBEはデータベースにSQLiteを使う設定で正しくインストール・実行されている
- SQLiteのファイルは `/ec-cube/var/sessions/eccube.db` を使用している
- 質問者の方はMySQLを使いたいと考えているが、EC-CUBEでMySQLを使う設定になっていないためエラーが発生した。

そこで、今後データベースの内容を取得・変更したいとのことですので、以下のような選択肢があります。

- EC-CUBEのデータベースとしてMySQLを使うように設定し直す。
- EC-CUBEの設定はそのままで、SQLiteの操作方法を学び、SQLiteの操作をできるようになる。

もし現在構築しているシステムが商用のものでしたら前者をおすすめします（MySQLとSQLiteの違いについては脱線になるので今回は説明しません）。